# Failed to start proxychain.service: Unit proxychain.service not found

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, proxychains

I installed proxychains on Ubuntu 22 I get this error when I want to run :Failed to start proxychain.service: Unit proxychain.service not found.
i also get this error when I check if it is active or not :Unit proxychains.service could not be found.

Hello.
I installed proxychains on Ubuntu 22 I get this error when I want to run :Failed to start proxychain.service: Unit proxychain.service not found.
i also get this error when I check if it is active or not :Unit proxychains.service could not be found.